# Python Requests/Selenium hard scraping tables

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

website is: https://www.jao.eu/auctions#/

I need to get/scrape and save the tables ('AUCTION SPECIFICATIONS & RESULTS') present in jao.eu/auctions# that come after I operate selections in the  OUT AREA, IN AREA, TYPE, AUCTION ID, etc., fields

Example, I need to get the table that displays after selecting: OUT AREA = 'AT', IN AREA = 'CH', type = 'Daily', Date = '23/05/2021', AUCTION ID = ...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data you can simulate Ajax request with `requests` module. For example:

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.jao.eu/api/v1/auction/calls/getauctions"

payload = {
    "corridor": "AT-CH",
    "fromdate": "2021-05-22-22:00:00",
    "horizon": "Daily",
    "todate": "2021-05-23-21:59:59",
}

data = requests.post(url, json=payload).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for r in sorted(data[0]["results"], key=lambda k: k["productHour"]):
    print(
        r["productHour"],
        r["offeredCapacity"],
        r["requestedCapacity"],
        r["allocatedCapacity"],
        r["auctionPrice"],
    )
```

Prints:

```
00:00-01:00 403 2379 403 14.23
01:00-02:00 403 2440 403 14.9
02:00-03:00 403 2290 403 8.45
03:00-04:00 403 2290 403 5.34
04:00-05:00 403 2215 403 2
05:00-06:00 403 2240 403 1.98
06:00-07:00 403 2125 403 0.56
07:00-08:00 403 2102 403 0.53
08:00-09:00 403 2100 403 0.31
09:00-10:00 403 2100 403 0.31
10:00-11:00 403 2106 403 0.31
11:00-12:00 403 2189 403 0.88
12:00-13:00 403 2230 403 1
13:00-14:00 403 2240 403 1
14:00-15:00 403 2242 403 1
15:00-16:00 403 2148 403 0.68
16:00-17:00 403 1990 403 0.33
17:00-18:00 403 2007 403 0.34
18:00-19:00 403 1935 403 0.3
19:00-20:00 403 1935 402 0.15
20:00-21:00 403 1935 402 0.15
21:00-22:00 403 1935 402 0.15
22:00-23:00 403 1935 402 0.15
23:00-24:00 403 2036 403 0.25
```

Comment: Andrej thank you very much

May I know how / where do you find the keys for the payload?

Comment: @DavideTessarollo When you open Firefox Developer Tools -> Network Tab (in Chrome is similar) and do a new search, you will see this URL and data the page sends/receives to/from server.

Comment: Can you please get the string of values from those parameters?   
    "corridor": "BDL-NL-GB",
    "horizon": "Monthly",
    "month": "June",
    "year": "2020",
    "AuctionID": "BDL-NL-GB-M-BASE---200601-01",

Comment: and please, all the columns: 
OFFERED CAPACITY (MW),
ATC (MW),
RETURN (MW),
REQUESTED CAPACITY (MW),
ALLOCATED CAPACITY (MW),
PRICE (€/MWH)

Comment: @DavideTessarollo To not clutter the comment section, I suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok, I will proceed with another request, please follow up